# qmake 3.8 uses absolute path in Makefile

Tags: qmake

in a not Qt project I use pre-installed qmake from Qt3 for creating my makefiles. Later on a build-server only makefile should be used, so generated Makefile should be portable and should neither have dependencies to Qt nor to my machine.

Works fine for simple projects, but in some places qmake uses absolute paths. e.g.:

```
consumer/$(MAKEFILE): 
        @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) consumer/ || $(MKDIR) consumer/ 
        cd consumer/ && $(QMAKE) /home/valentinheinitz/Workspaces/hitrax3/trunk/sinogrambuff
```

Is there a switch for explicitly forbidding usage of absolute paths?